# proper syntax for appending to string/text

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have a variable string I'm trying to display through label text, however no matter what syntax I try the combination seems to simply break everything.

ex:

```
text="The value is: " + value
text=("The value is: " + value)
text="The value is: ", value
etc.
```

I've tried looking through the documentation but I'm not really finding anything to indicate the proper way to do so, so if anyone has some direction for me it'd be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Nikunj Chaklasiya solved it for me, the mismatched types were causing an error so I had to convert the integers to strings first.

Comment: You Combine string tried to display as Label text?

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you're asking me. I'm trying to append a variable integer to a default string in a label.text. I can use the string, or the integer, but for some reason I'm unable to combine the two (literally the entire screen just goes blank and nothing runs).

Comment: I thing Its Conversion problem. pls, tried to text="The value is: " + value.ToStr()

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Post that as the answer so I can give you points lol.

Comment: It's helpful to you?

Comment: yes, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Every Roku Developer faces difficulty. The compiler does not give a proper error.

So, you write 3 lines for print But, Here only allow "+" sign, not a "," to combine a string. And Do Not a combine a different Datatype value without conversion.

```
textstr="The value is: " + value.ToStr() 'Integer to String
textint= 10 + "10".ToInt()'String to Integer
```

you should also check Both Data type using "type"

```
?type(textstr)
?type(textint)
```